# Scilab: Parameters estimation on Lotka Volterra model Scilab

Tags: optimization, parameters, scilab, estimation

I have tried to reproduce the script of the following link:
[Parameters estimation on Lotka Volterra model with Scilab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22614164/parameters-estimation-on-lotka-volterra-model-with-scilab/45860020?noredirect=1#comment78679540_45860020)

And I get similar errors in the results to those described in it..
You could guide me to run the script without errors.
Gracias
Hermes

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parameters estimation on Lotka Volterra model with Scilab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22614164/parameters-estimation-on-lotka-volterra-model-with-scilab)

Answer (score 0):

## Solution for Scilab 5.5.1 or smaller

The problem is that the solver somehow reach a point where it cannot solve the ode on every `t` and stops at a certain point. Thus your `y_calc` is smaller than `y_exp` in size.

If this is not a problem for you, change `diffmat` on line 6 of the `Differences` function to

```
diffmat = y_calc' - y_exp(1:size(y_calc',1),:)
```

## Solution for Scilab 6.0.0 or greater

The `ode` function now raise an error when it fails to compute in Scilab 6.X.X.

Using the `try ... catch ... end` statements, we can let the program deal with it.

So a wrong (and i will explain why after) solution is changing line 5 of `Differences` function to

```
try // test if ode works normally
  [y_calc,odew,odeiw]=ode(y0',t0,t,list(LotkaVolterra,c,n,m,e)) 
catch // if an error is raised
  y_calc = y_exp' // Put a value when the computations fails
end
diffmat = y_calc' - y_exp(1:size(y_calc',1),:)
```

You would still get warning from ode.

## Why it is bad

Since you asked for a running program, i've used the `try catch` statement to toss away the error and let the program continue. You should not. It means that your problem is ill defined: the parameters are poorly chosen or it's not numerically solvable. I recommend to work on the mathematics behind the program and find why some parameters may break the `ode` algorithm.

And there's another reason you should not follow my answer. As you see, when I catch an error, I give to `y_calc` some value. But that's mathematically absurd because an optimization problem rely on the fact that the solution approximate at best the initial problem. I'm 99% sure that the `y_calc = y_exp'` statement will gives you unusable results.